# Grid Serialize not working for second grid checkbox

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, grid-serlization

I have admin form with grid. in my grid i have set checkbox as another form field but it gives disabled when it rendered.My code is as below.

Layout file.

```
<shippinggroup_adminhtml_shippinggroup_customers>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="shippinggroup/adminhtml_shippinggroup_edit_tab_formcustomer" name="shippinggroup.edit.tab.formcustomer" />
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="customer_grid_serializer" >
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>shippinggroup.edit.tab.formcustomer</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedCustomers</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[customer_ids]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>customer</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>warrantymail</input_name>
               </action>

        </block>
    </block>
</shippinggroup_adminhtml_shippinggroup_customers>
```

grid column.

```
$this->addColumn('customer_ids', array(
        'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
        'type'              => 'checkbox',
        'name'              => 'customer_ids',
        'values'            => $this->_getSelectedCustomers(),
        'align'             => 'center',
        'index'             => 'entity_id'
    ));
   $this->addColumn('position', array(
        'header'            => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
        'name'              => 'position',
        'type'              => 'checkbox',
        'validate_class'    => 'validate-number',
        'index'             => 'position',
        'values'            => '',
    ));
```

Here is screenshot of output https://www.screencast.com/t/xCqsQ6NCF

I would also like to display label for column.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

your **data_callback** is **getSelectedCustomers**

```
<data_callback>getSelectedCustomers</data_callback>
```

and you are calling

```
'values'            => $this->_getSelectedCustomers(),
```

change it to

```
'values'            => $this->getSelectedCustomers(),
```

Comment: that is not the main point.i have two checkbox in one grid i want it work separately and post in form.currently it render disable when edit record.when i checked on first checkbox it also check all the second column checkbox too.

Comment: @MageLerner you want to get post values of this gird? on based on that add some column?

Comment: yes exactly i would like it work seperately both checkbox and post

Comment: @MageLerner you can get grid values simply use this code  `$this->getRequest()->getPost('customer')`

Comment: yes i can but second checkbox is not working correctly dear

Comment: @MageLerner it will return array if you want to select single item at a time then  use radio button in grid.

Comment: you are not getting my point my checkbox is currently depend on first checkbox that is not good. i want independent checkbox for this column please check this video.https://www.screencast.com/t/nUTLprkB

Comment: @MageLerner if you select the column 1 checkbox what will be happens in next column?

Comment: i select column 1 checkbox it also select column 2 checkbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53543/discussion-between-magelerner-and-qaisar-satti).